# Problema en instalación de Android en Qt Creator

Tags: android, qt

Quiero desarrollar aplicaciones Android utilizado desde Qt Designer(c++), descargando e instalando lo siguiente:
**qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.8.0 y sdk, ndk, ant y jdk**. 
Todo esto desde el link indicado en Qt.
Seguí al pie de la letra las instrucciones para instalar android en mi Qt. En la ventana de Options-tools, agregue todos los archivos y agregue API 25(version):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya instale lo necesario en sdk manager:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que al momento de agregar la ubicación de estos archivos debe de agregar los kits cuando creo un proyecto, pero a mi no me los agrega. No se si sea mi version de Qt que es MinGW 5.9. Cualquier comentario es agradecido y si no me di a entender, con gusto les aclaro.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aquí les dejo un enlace con un tutorial en español paso a paso para desarrollar aplicaciones con Qt para Android. Hay otros artículos relacionados con Qt. https://0xdac.org/blog/index.php/2017/04/03/comenzando-con-qt-para-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, pero cuando yo instale Qt para android tuve un problema que es bastante común y fácil de solucionar.
Lo que tenes que hacer es descargar la carpeta tools de el siguiente link:
Linux:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip
Si tenes otro sistema operativo, simplemente remplaza esta parte  /tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip por lo siguiente dependiendo de tu sistema operativo.
MacOS:
/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip
Windows:
/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip

Una vez descargada la carpeta, tenes que descomprimirla y reemplazar la carpeta tools en tu carpeta de android, que en mi caso se encuentra en la siguiente dirección /home/Android/sdk.
Suerte.

Comment: Gracias por la info, la verdad no logré usar Android en Qt. Tienes algún link donde diga como instalar android en Qt, te lo agradecería.

Comment: Si tengo un instructivo como instarlo, para windows o linux lo necesitas?

Comment: para windows, gracias

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TjeEXaMa-EODJWenBzQmZlUTRBay1iUE1ReFliRlJTRURJ/view?usp=sharing